# Python/Kivy and Android environment: Pandas module not found

Tags: python, android, kivy

I am trying to create a simple Android application using Python and Kivy. As part of this, I am importing `pandas`. This all seems to work fine when I run it in on my Windows PC. I am creating the Android app using Python for Android.

When I run it in an Android environment I get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

What could cause the module to not properly build into the app? I can't seem to find an answer.

Below is the complete log. Thanks.

```
2020-04-25 15:38:05.723 8066-8066/? W/SDLThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:29030): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/com.graffbt.coronaviruscp/files/app/_python_bundle/modules/math.cpython-38.so" dev="sda35" ino=670093 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file
2020-04-25 15:38:05.726 8066-8066/? W/SDLThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:29031): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/com.graffbt.coronaviruscp/files/app/_python_bundle/modules/_queue.cpython-38.so" dev="sda35" ino=670132 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file
2020-04-25 15:38:05.766 8066-8066/? W/SDLThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:29032): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/com.graffbt.coronaviruscp/files/app/_python_bundle/modules/_bisect.cpython-38.so" dev="sda35" ino=670095 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file
2020-04-25 15:38:05.773 8066-8066/? W/SDLThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:29033): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/com.graffbt.coronaviruscp/files/app/_python_bundle/modules/_sha512.cpython-38.so" dev="sda35" ino=670115 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file
2020-04-25 15:38:05.776 8066-8066/? W/SDLThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:29034): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/com.graffbt.coronaviruscp/files/app/_python_bundle/modules/_random.cpython-38.so" dev="sda35" ino=670144 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file
2020-04-25 15:38:05.796 8066-8066/? W/SDLThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:29035): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/com.graffbt.coronaviruscp/files/app/_python_bundle/modules/_opcode.cpython-38.so" dev="sda35" ino=670086 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file
2020-04-25 15:38:05.853 8025-8066/com.graffbt.coronaviruscp I/python: [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/com.graffbt.coronaviruscp/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-04-25_1.txt
2020-04-25 15:38:05.853 8025-8066/com.graffbt.coronaviruscp I/python: [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
2020-04-25 15:38:05.853 8025-8066/com.graffbt.coronaviruscp I/python: [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/com.graffbt.coronaviruscp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
2020-04-25 15:38:05.853 8025-8066/com.graffbt.coronaviruscp I/python: [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.1 (default, Apr 20 2020, 03:42:32) 
2020-04-25 15:38:05.853 8025-8066/com.graffbt.coronaviruscp I/python: [Clang 8.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang 40173bab62ec7462
2020-04-25 15:38:05.854 8025-8066/com.graffbt.coronaviruscp I/python: [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at ""
2020-04-25 15:38:05.855 8025-8066/com.graffbt.coronaviruscp I/python:  Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-04-25 15:38:05.855 8025-8066/com.graffbt.coronaviruscp I/python:    File "/content/main.py", line 3, in <module>
2020-04-25 15:38:05.856 8025-8066/com.graffbt.coronaviruscp I/python:  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
2020-04-25 15:38:05.856 8025-8066/com.graffbt.coronaviruscp I/python: Python for android ended.
```

Answer (score 0):

you would need to add `pandas` in the requirements of `buildozer spec file`

Comment: I am using python for android and added `pandas` to my requirements. If you have another idea, please edit this one. Thanks!